# How to make appendchild method on top of elements

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a ul elements and it spawns li elements using js

```js
var newli = document.createElement("li")
newli.innerHTML = "1"
document.getElementById('ulmain').appendChild(newli);
```

```html
<ul id="ulmain">
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```

and as you can see, the 1 spawned below the 4. But I need the 1 spawn below of 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `appendChild()` method adds a node to the *end of the list* of children of a specified parent.

**You can use [prepend()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/prepend) to insert before the first child of the `ul`**

```
document.getElementById('ulmain').prepend(newli);
```

---

Working Code

```js
var newli = document.createElement("li")
newli.innerHTML = "1"
document.getElementById('ulmain').prepend(newli);
```

```html
<ul id="ulmain">
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```